# How to halt system via script with no user input?

Tags: 14.04, bash, sudo, shutdown

My system runs headless, starts when power is applied, and at the end of the boot automatically starts some software through a *.conf* file in */etc/init*.  This starts the script that starts the software.  The script waits until the last app exits (the others will already have exited) and then attempts to *halt* the computer so it may be safely powered off.

I cannot make the *halt* work.  If the computer is not shut down properly it *may* hang the next time power is supplied as it apparently waits forever for a response.

I've tried editing the */etc/sudoers* to allow */sbin/halt* to not require a password, have tried to do the same with a script containing the command */sbin/halt* but nothing has worked; the last app runs, quits, and then nothing happens.

How can a script be fashioned to automatically *halt* the machine?

/etc/init conf file:

```
description "Copies fireimager executeables to the ram disk and executes them."
author "Robert Lockwood"

start on net-device-up
stop on shutdown

script
echo "[`date`] Fireimager initializing Started" >> /var/log/fireimager.log
exec /home/programmer/bin/init/inittest

end script
```

/home/programmer/bin/init/inittest (fragment)

```
#!/bin/bash
# this script is extecuted by root when the interfaces become active.
# when the last application shuts down the computer is commanded to shut down.

# start the micro-server 
su -c "/home/programmer/bin/startServer &" user-name password -

# start fireimager controller 
su -c "/home/programmer/bin/startController" user-name password -
# following appears in the log
echo "[`date '+%a %b %2d %T.%3N %Z %Y'`] Starting poweroff" >> /var/log/fireimager.log

# when the controller shuts down, then poweroff FAILS
su -c "sudo /home/programer/bin/halt" user-name password -
```

~/bin/halt script

```
#!/bin/bash         
# This should halt the computer

/sbin/halt
```

Comment: You're already root. Why do you become a user then use sudo? `su -c "sudo /home/programer/bin/halt" user-name password -` -- why not simple `/sbin/halt`

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how I missed the 'easy' way.  In any event if you Answer my post I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already root, instead of the complicated

```
su -c "sudo /home/programer/bin/halt" user-name password -
```

keep it simple

```
/sbin/halt
```